# Setting mailgun dns TXT record on gcloud

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, mailgun, spf, google-cloud-dns

I have been trying to add mailgun dns TXT record on google cloud dns, with the data provided by mailgun,

**Type** *TXT*

**Hostname** *mydomain.org*

**Enter This Value** *v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all*

[mailgun required data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrCD8.png)

I entered the whole information on google cloud dns as I though it should be. Other ones worked well, except this particular **TXT** data.

**google cloud dns record**

I coppied the data provided by mailgun (**v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all**). But after cppied the txt data and pasted it on google cloud dns, under TXT, double quotation mark will automatically be added giving me the following result after saving it **("v=spf1" "include:mailgun.org" "~all")**, which is normal.

[google cloud dns record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do5NH.png)

But after all the settings, mailgun will not recognize it, as you can see on the first image.

Please guys, what should I do about this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried putting double quotes around the entire record value when adding it in the Google Cloud console?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but either of the following worked for me :-

"v=spf1\ include:mailgun.org\ ~all"
or
v=spf1\ include:mailgun.org\ ~all

The backslash makes the space literal I think. Can't remember which of the above worked, but it does work.

Comment: this works. v=spf1\ include:mailgun.org\ ~all

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hint: https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en

" Create a TXT record with these values:
**Name/Host/Alias—Enter @ or leave blank**.
Other DNS records for your domain might indicate the correct entry."